# Cutomizing handles/requests for the CURL package

Tags: r, curl, sftp, libcurl

I am trying to interact with a SFTP server from inside R. The `CURL` package came highly recommended. Not `RCURL` but `CURL`.

One of the things I am trying to do is get a list of directories/files at an address. I have the code working so far:

```
# create a new curl handle 
han <- new_handle()

# set options for SFTP
handle_setopt(han, verbose = TRUE)

# execute the request 
result <- curl_fetch_memory(url = "{SFTP URL here}",handle = han)

# get the response data 
response <- rawToChar(result$content)
```

**The SFTP server at this URL does not have passwords. The remote has SFTP protocol version 3**

The above code almost does what I am looking for, `curl_fetch_memory(url = "{SFTP URL here}",handle = han)` produces a list with among other things `result$content` that has the the said list of directories/files but with everything as in file names, dates and permission data all in the chars.

1. How to customize the request/handle to get the list of files in a cleaner manner? Just a plain list of files akin to `ls` on SFTP servers? If this is at all possible. (copies of `result` and `response` attached below.)
2. If customizing the requests is not possible, is there a way to customize `CURL` objects to make them a bit more human readable?

Output for `response`

```
$url
[1] "sftp://data.cyverse.org/shared/"

$status_code
[1] 0

$type
[1] NA

$headers
raw(0)

$modified
[1] "2020-02-20 16:05:33 CST"

$times
     redirect    namelookup       connect   pretransfer starttransfer 
     0.000000      0.000029      0.000000      0.230600      0.000000 
        total 
     0.230608 

$content
  [1] 64 72 77 78 72 2d 78 72 2d 78 20 20 20 20 31 20 30 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20
 [26] 30 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 30 20 44 65 63 20 33 31 20
 [51] 20 31 39 36 39 20 2e 0a 64 72 77 78 72 2d 78 72 2d 78 20 20 20 20 31 20 30
 [76] 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 30 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 30
[101] 20 44 65 63 20 33 31 20 20 31 39 36 39 20 2e 2e 0a 64 72 77 78 72 2d 78 72
[126] 2d 78 20 20 20 20 31 20 30 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 30 20 20 20 20 20 20 20
[151] 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 30 20 46 65 62 20 32 30 20 20 32 30 32 30 20 61 6c
[176] 69 67 6e 6d 65 6e 74 73 5f 61 6e 64 5f 74 72 65 65 73 0a 64 72 77 78 72 2d
[201] 78 72 2d 78 20 20 20 20 31 20 30 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 30 20 20 20 20 20
[226] 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 30 20 46 65 62 20 32 30 20 20 32 30 32 30 20
[251] 67 65 6e 65 5f 66 61 6d 69 6c 79 5f 65 76 6f 6c 75 74 69 6f 6e 0a 64 72 77
[276] 78 72 2d 78 72 2d 78 20 20 20 20 31 20 30 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 30 20 20
[301] 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 30 20 46 65 62 20 32 30 20 20 32 30
[326] 32 30 20 6d 61 70 73 5f 73 63 72 69 70 74 73 0a 64 72 77 78 72 2d 78 72 2d
[351] 78 20 20 20 20 31 20 30 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 30 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20
[376] 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 30 20 46 65 62 20 32 30 20 20 32 30 32 30 20 74 72 61
[401] 6e 73 63 72 69 70 74 5f 61 73 73 65 6d 62 6c 69 65 73 0a 64 72 77 78 72 2d
[426] 78 72 2d 78 20 20 20 20 31 20 30 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 30 20 20 20 20 20
[451] 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 30 20 46 65 62 20 32 30 20 20 32 30 32 30 20
[476] 77 68 6f 6c 65 5f 67 65 6e 6f 6d 65 5f 64 75 70 6c 69 63 61 74 69 6f 6e 73
[501] 0a 2d 72 77 2d 72 2d 2d 72 2d 2d 20 20 20 20 31 20 30 20 20 20 20 20 20 20
[526] 20 30 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 36 36 39 20 4f 63 74 20 31 32
[551] 20 20 32 30 31 39 20 67 65 6e 65 5f 66 61 6d 69 6c 69 65 73 5f 6f 72 74 68
[576] 6f 66 69 6e 64 65 72 2e 74 78 74 0a 2d 72 77 2d 72 2d 2d 72 2d 2d 20 20 20
[601] 20 31 20 30 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 30 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20
[626] 31 32 37 33 20 4f 63 74 20 31 32 20 20 32 30 31 39 20 72 65 61 64 6d 65 2e
[651] 74 78 74 0a
```

output for `result$content`

```
'drwxr-xr-x    1 0        0               0 Dec 31  1969 .\ndrwxr-xr-x    1 0        0               0 Dec 31  1969 ..\ndrwxr-xr-x    1 0        0               0 Nov 7  2020 curated\n'
```

Comment: Q1: if supported, I suspect this would be vendor-specific; which sftp vendor/version is being used on the remote end? Q2: please provide a sample of the output; we don't have access to your sftp server, and it's possible (even likely) that different sftp servers have varying output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set [CURLOPT_DIRLISTONLY](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_DIRLISTONLY.html) to only list names. Though you can also parse default response as a regular tabular text, i.e. with `read.table()`, or `readr::read_table()`. Options for `curl` package are general libcurl options from upstream, so libcurl documentation can be used as a reference - https://curl.se/libcurl/c/easy_setopt_options.html

Using [Rebex](https://test.rebex.net/) demo server as an example:

```r
library(curl)
#> Using libcurl 7.84.0 with Schannel
# https://test.rebex.net/
SFTP_DEMO <- "sftp://demo:password@test.rebex.net:22"
han <- new_handle()

# list all libcurl options that include "list"
curl_options("list")
#>            cookielist           dirlistonly proxy_ssl_cipher_list 
#>                 10135                    48                 10259 
#>       ssl_cipher_list 
#>                 10083
# set dirlistonly
handle_setopt(han, dirlistonly = TRUE)

# dirlistonly request: 
file_list <- curl_fetch_memory(url = SFTP_DEMO, handle = han)[["content"]] |> rawToChar()

cat(file_list)
#> .
#> ..
#> pub
#> readme.txt
read.table(text = file_list)
#>           V1
#> 1          .
#> 2         ..
#> 3        pub
#> 4 readme.txt
strsplit(file_list, "\n") |> unlist()
#> [1] "."          ".."         "pub"        "readme.txt"

# you can do the same with detailed file list:
handle_setopt(han, dirlistonly = FALSE)
curl_fetch_memory(url = SFTP_DEMO,
                  handle = han)[["content"]] |>
  rawToChar() |>
  read.table(text = _)
#>           V1 V2   V3    V4  V5  V6 V7    V8         V9
#> 1 drwx------  2 demo users   0 Mar 31 17:52          .
#> 2 drwx------  2 demo users   0 Mar 31 17:52         ..
#> 3 drwx------  2 demo users   0 Mar 31 17:52        pub
#> 4 -rw-------  1 demo users 405 Dec 17  2021 readme.txt
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Perfect! This does quite well. If I may, where can I learn about `curl_options()`? I am generally having difficult working with `CURL` (the package) because `CURL_OPTIONS()` lists all the options without actually describing what the options are. `CURL` works around  `handles` and `handles` work around `curl_options()` but the documentation only lists them without saying what each one does.

Comment: As options are not specific to `curl` R package, you can use libcurl docs as reference - https://curl.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html & https://curl.se/libcurl/c/easy_setopt_options.html

Comment: Ahh! So, that's the context I am missing. Thank you!